# NoMethodError in PostsController#create "creating nested form multi tables"

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, database, input, controller

I have a nested form with `post` and `place.` I want to get both data entries into the database upon submit. I have a foreign key in the place table called `post_id`. How would i keep them related on submit like the foreign key of post will give the post id and everything will be submitted `post` and `place`?? Thank you!!!

**Post controller:**

```rails
class PostsController < ApplicationController

before_action :authenticate_user!, :except => [:show, :index, :new]

before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

before_action :owned_post, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]  

  def index
    @post = Post.new
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  def show

    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new

    @post = current_user.posts.new
    @post.places = Place.new


  end

  def create

    @post = current_user.posts.create(post_params)



    if @post.save
      flash[:success] = "Your post has been created!"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Your new post couldn't be created!  Please check the form."
      render :new
    end
  end

  def find
    @place = Place.new
  end

  def edit
    @place = @post.place;
  end

  def update
     if @post.update(post_params)
      flash[:success] = "Post updated."
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = "Update failed.  Please check the form."
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @post.destroy

    flash[:success] = "Your Post has been removed."
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  private



  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:place_id, :image, :caption, :places_attributes => [:id, :post_id, :city, :country, :address, :streetnumber, :street, :state])

  end

  def place_params
    params.require(:place).permit(:country, :city)
  end




  def set_post
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def owned_post  
  unless current_user == @post.user
    flash[:alert] = "That post doesn't belong to you!"
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end  

end
```

**Form  -home.html:**

```html
<%= simple_form_for @post, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <%= f.error_notification %>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="dont">
            <h4>Upload an image (this is required):</h4>
            <%= f.input :image, label: false, input_html: { onChange: 'loadFile(event)' } %>
          </div>
          <%= f.simple_fields_for :places do |o| %>
          <div class="dont">
            <%= o.input :address, label: false, placeholder: "search", class: 'controls',:input_html =>{:id => 'pac-input'} %>
           <input id="latitude" name="latitude" value=" @#{latitude} "  type="text">
           <input id="longitude" name="longitude" value=" @#{longitude} " type="text">
           <input id="action" name="action" value"test" type="hidden">
           <%= o.input :streetnumber, label: false, class: 'controls',:input_html =>{:id => 'streetnumber'},:as => :hidden %>
           <%= o.input :street, label: false, class: 'controls',:input_html =>{:id => 'street'}, :as => :hidden %>
           <%= o.input :city, label: false, class: 'controls',:input_html =>{:id => 'city'}, :as => :hidden %>
           <%= o.input :state, label: false, class: 'controls',:input_html =>{:id => 'state'}, :as => :hidden %>
           <%= o.input :country, label: false, class: 'controls',:input_html =>{:id => 'country'}, :as => :text, :as => :hidden %>
          </div>
          <% end %>
          
          <div class="dont">
            <%= f.input :caption, label: false, placeholder: 'Add your caption' %>
          </div>
          <div class="dont">
            <%= f.button :submit, class: 'btn-success btn-block' %>
          </div>
        </div>
        <% end %>
```

**Error Report:**

`
Started POST "/posts" for ::1 at 2016-05-11 20:14:53 +0900
Processing by PostsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"cJP0UGjMFD244w2D4DqLC+VV86wO/i+ScOxbKUowMKSxx9JnwOQ77EFeyLAZY1E3/YSQnOOZ2nIbu/Dc9mok6w==", "post"=>{"image"=>#, @original_filename="IMG_0645.JPG", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"post[image]\"; filename=\"IMG_0645.JPG\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, "places"=>{"address"=>"Unnamed Road, Mokro, Bosnia and Herzegovina", "streetnumber"=>"undefined", "street"=>"Unnamed Road", "city"=>"Mokro", "state"=>"Republika Srpska", "country"=>"Bosnia and Herzegovina"}, "caption"=>""}, "latitude"=>"43.88522775121559", "longitude"=>"18.6328125", "commit"=>"Create Post"}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 16]]
Unpermitted parameter: places
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
Command :: file -b --mime '/var/folders/tb/nnp8bs4x34b4ylvjsgq5g0400000gn/T/6b1516dec860140f099ec2a5d5cbbd6320160511-94657-1fkkpgg.JPG'
Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/var/folders/tb/nnp8bs4x34b4ylvjsgq5g0400000gn/T/6b1516dec860140f099ec2a5d5cbbd6320160511-94657-noib0w.JPG[0]' 2>/dev/null
Command :: identify -format %m '/var/folders/tb/nnp8bs4x34b4ylvjsgq5g0400000gn/T/6b1516dec860140f099ec2a5d5cbbd6320160511-94657-noib0w.JPG[0]'
Command :: convert '/var/folders/tb/nnp8bs4x34b4ylvjsgq5g0400000gn/T/6b1516dec860140f099ec2a5d5cbbd6320160511-94657-noib0w.JPG[0]' -auto-orient -resize "640" '/var/folders/tb/nnp8bs4x34b4ylvjsgq5g0400000gn/T/74ec5b80c34294faf295a1917f07ae9720160511-94657-1rtm7lc'
Command :: file -b --mime '/var/folders/tb/nnp8bs4x34b4ylvjsgq5g0400000gn/T/6b1516dec860140f099ec2a5d5cbbd6320160511-94657-1rirdao.JPG'

`

Thank you!!

Comment: Please update your question with full  error message

Comment: Iv been working on it and changed some things. im not as much getting an error but my places table isnt populating with the place input box values still. so i edited both forms and added the error message! thanks!!!

Comment: Unpermitted parameters `places`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your PostController new method add

```
 @post = current_user.posts.new
 @places = @post.places.build
```

And in you Post model add

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :places
```